# checkbox format number javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a problem: when I sum the price (the base price is 500.000, and I want to sum 20.000) it change the total to 520 and not 520.000. and when i sum the othet price (1000 + 17,78) the price is licke 27.780 i think i need to format the number but I don't know how. Can someone help me?

Please see the [website link](https://www.tecmasolutions.com/clients/home-configurator-1/checkout.php?tipo=B.4&stile=classic&allestimento=silver&pavimento=Floogres%20greentech%20-%20colore%20TAN)

here's the code:

```js
//sommo rata e prezzo dei plus a quelli del DB
var basicPrice_rata = 1000; // This is how we start
var basicPrice_prezzo = 50000; // This is how we start

$(document).on('change', getCheck);

function getCheck() {
  var currentPrice_rata = basicPrice_rata; // every time
  CurrentPrice_rata = basicPrice_rata;
  var currentPrice_prezzo = basicPrice_prezzo; // every time
  CurrentPrice_prezzo = basicPrice_prezzo;
  plus = [],
    total_rata = 1000;
  total_prezzo = 50000;

  $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(i, el) {
    total_rata += parseInt($(el).data('rata'));
    total_prezzo += parseInt($(el).data('prezzo'));
    //console.log(total_rata);
    plus.push($(el).data('name')); // get the label text
  });

  //inserisco i nomi dei plus nella riga di testo
  $("#plus-display").text(plus.join(", "));

  //inserisco le rate sommate  nei div corrispondenti
  $('#rata-display-2').text(total_rata + " €");

  //inserisco i prezzi sommati  nei div corrispondenti
  $('#prezzo-somma').text(total_prezzo + " €");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<input type="checkbox" data-rata="134.24" data-prezzo="20000" id="posto-auto" name="posto auto" data-name="posto auto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" data-rata="17.78" data-prezzo="5000" id="posto-moto" name="Posto moto" data-name="Posto moto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">
<input type="checkbox" data-rata="134.24" data-prezzo="40000" id="box-auto" name="Box auto" data-name="Box auto" class="check-plus w-checkbox-input">

<div id="rata-display-2" class="prezzo-checkout">1000 €</div>
<div id="prezzo-somma" class="text-checkout color bold">500000 €</div>
<div id="plus-display" class="text_piccolo black checkout">Interior Pack Incluso nel prezzo</div>
```

Comment: parseInt means turn this into an integer. An integer is a whole number.

Comment: `total_prezzo` is 50 000 on init, but you have in HTML hardcoded 500 000

Answer (score 0):

When you read the data you do a [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> The **parseInt()** function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

What you want, however, is a float, not an integer. You can use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

> The **parseFloat()** function parses an argument and returns a floating point number.